# Is it possible to programmatically send an email without the signature in an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating an app which sends brings up the mail composer to send an email. It is possible for it not to have the signature show up?

Comment: If the user wants their signature to be appended to all emails that they send, shouldn't you respect that? (rhetorical question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the signature stays.

You could however implement you own e-mail editing and send via your own backend. Doesn't sound too compelling though.

Answer (score 4):

no you cant, its part of the OS system settings, which you cant override.